# Problem logging in even though password is accepted

Tags: 12.04

I am logged in as `user_a`. I created another account `user_b` with root privileges using the following steps:

```
sudo -s
useradd user_b
passwd user_b
>sum_passwd
sudo adduser user_b admin
```

After which I rebooted and tried to login as `user_b` but after typing the password, I see momentary darkness and then the login screen again. This does not happen if I try to type some incorrect password, as I am prompted immediately. I can login just fine to the guest_account and `user_a` but the newly created `user_b` is causing problems.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

you used a password that is the same as the username? If so, I believe that Ubuntu doesn't like this. If not, have you checked the useradd GUI that ships with Ubuntu to ensure that user_b is listed?

Comment: The question doesnt' seem to say the password is the same as the username. And if it were, that wouldn't be a problem (except that it would be a very easy password to guess)--Ubuntu doesn't have a problem with that. Furthermore, `useradd` is a command-line program, not a graphical utility.